# Is it possible to center a single item on a listview?

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview

I have a custom listview in a relative layout and I was wondering if it **is possible to center a single item in a listview?** The custom adapter handles two TextView fields from the custom_listview.xml

```
For example:
My List view

A    B
C    D
   E
F    G
```

I've included my xml layouts below.

summary.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.myapp.Summary">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/Welcome" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mainListView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Welcome"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Side navigation drawer UI -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navList"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="#ffeeeeee"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

custom_listview.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Please wait.."
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/txtFieldName" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Please wait.."
        android:id="@+id/txtFieldValue" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you set the `Gravity` to `center` programatically on that particular element. If you use the ViewHolder pattern, make sure you set the other ones to default.

Comment: yes, change item layout to be like `<FrameLayout> <YourCurrentLayout  /><theCenterLayout/></FrameLayout>` ... now depends on your needs hide/show `theCenterLayout`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, Please post your comment as an answer and I will accept it. Since I'm doing my fair share of hat tricks, I could not directly set gravity to center as all my items in the list shifted. I'm using an if statement to determine when to apply the center gravity and it is working great. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `Gravity` to `CENTER` programatically on that particular element to center it in your Adapter's `getView()` method. If you use the ViewHolder pattern, make sure you set the other ones to default; so you'll need an `if/else` statement.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this in your situation is to set the second `TextView`'s `Visibility` to `View.GONE`. Since you are wrapping the `TextView`s in a `LinearLayout` and the first view has a `weight` attribute, it will fill the whole parent layout when there are no "sibling" views for it.

In this case, you have to be careful to reset the visibility of the second item in your `getView` method using an `if/else` statement.

Keep in mind that the `View` will have the same width as the parent in this case - even though it's written as `wrap_content`, it will fill all the horizontal space contained by the parent, effectively rendering it as `match_parent`.